# Create a Task if Contact is in certain status for 10 days

Tags: workflow, process-builder, tasks, time-dependent-workflow

A task should be created to assigned user when Contact is in "Attempted Call" status for 10 Days. How can I create a task?

I have created a Number field - "Con_Days__c"

Work Flow Rule(any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria) - `Contact Status = "Attempted Call"`

Added a Time Based Action -

```
 "10 Days after Contact status Updated Date"
, Action  - Update "Con_Days__c" = 10
```

Process Builder -

```
If Contact status ="Attempted call"
con_Days__c = 10
con_Days__c ISCHANGED Boolean True
```

The field gets updated to 10, but a task is not being created. If there is any other workaround please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd use a Workflow Rule for this. Simply build this in the Process Builder *or* Workflow Rule entirely.

As for the Process Builder, it would be:

- Trigger when a record is modified
- Contact object -> When it meets the criteria
- Criteria -> Status equals Attempted Call
- Delayed Action -> 10 Days After Trigger -> Create Task

The same logic would work for a Workflow Rule, too.

Comment: My criteria is if Contact status is in "Attempted Call" status for 10 Days then a task should be created that contact is in that status for 10 days. In your explanation, if the status changes from "attempted call' to 'reached' after 5 days, a task will still be created after 10 days even though contact is in 'reached' status. Let me know if I am not clear, thanks

Comment: @Sfdclearner No, it won't. If the criteria no longer meets the criteria, it will not create the task. You should try this out for yourself; it has always worked this way.

Comment: @sfdcfox what if the field status changed 2 times x to y and then again y to x. ? This time, when it is creating task, it will check condition and it will true. Please confirm.

Comment: Update: I tried this. sfdcfox was right. It rechecks the condition everytime. You can check the scheduled action in FLOWs(in classic->setup->flow->Active -> you should see your scheduled entry.

Comment: Got it! I tested it with workflow and Process builder and it worked, Thank you so much for helping me! @Sfdcfox and YsrShk